# Setting environment variables Linux

Tags: java, git, tomcat, oracle11g, environment-variables

I am configuring my study environment :) on Linux server: I have installed java, oracle database, tomcat, and I have set JAVA_HOME, ORACLE_HOME variables for all users and modified the .bash_profile files as I read it is the only way to make things permanently set. However I am not sure what variables do I need to set for TOMCAT, when I try to start tomcat from another user different from root[even here I have to go inside tomcat's bin folder], I see that the process is trying to use CATALINA_HOME, CATALINA_BASE,CATALINA_TMPDIR and CLASSPATH [for bootstrap.sh (I am not sure why it needs bootstrap.sh)], anyway my question is which variables do I need to set for tomcat? Do I need to set all of them in root and all other users .bash_profile files? I need some clearification because I am really fed up with configuration having a lot to know beyond that, just need help.

More to that I think I have installed MAVEN [MAVEN_HOME not set either], I say I think because  when I try

```
 locate maven
```

I have the following result:

```
/etc/maven
/etc/maven/maven2-depmap.xml
/usr/local/apache/tomcat/apache-tomcat-6.0.37/webapps/docs/maven-jars.html
/usr/share/java-utils/xml/maven2jpp-mapdeps.xsl
```

If I try the following I have not output

```
locate maven | grep bin
```

[Not sure if this is a good question to ask the server, since deep in /etc/maven ls -la show me there is total 32 but I can only see maven2-depmap.xml]

The question is, looking at the files found when I tried locate maven, can anyone tell if I have installed it or not? :):)

Further I need To install GIT  following some installation guide I had found it is been a week I don't really remember which one was that, I started by downloading curl_devel, gettext_devel some other *_devel stuff [I don't know what they are and not sure if I should know about them] and when I tried to install them, they required git to be installed I looked around for git packages to download but after 7 to 10 minutes I didn't find where I can really get git packages, but since I didn't give it much attention this question is not as important as others. what I want to know is, once I get git installed which environment variables will I have to set?

Thank you very much for taking time to read and help. I appreciate.

Answer (score -1):

I think the other simple round about can the changing the user of the TOMCAT.  Set it to the root user.

This will be useful only if you have set correct path and tomcat is working properly with root user.

I also dont know if this is recommended or not.

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice either. because I can go round and start tomcat as root as I am the only user.

Comment: very bad idea running processes as root. it's the lazy way of working out how to configure things correctly.

Comment: Nothing wrong with lazy @MarkFisher :-) - without lazy we would all still be hunter-gatherers.  (Im not saying its a good idea to run a process as root, just that its not bad because its lazy - its bad because its insecure and could potentially damage your system).